# Windows 7 gui doesn't display a mapped drive b:

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, subst

This is an annoyance more than a roadblock, but it doesn't seem to make sense.

On my XP box, I got used to subst or mapping drive A: to my general notes and work in progress folders, and drive B: was my current project's source code that I was working on.  As these are historical drives that don't get used by a hardware device anymore, I felt safe using them.

Now on Win7 - I can subst or map either drive and use them at the command, but the Windows GUI does not seem to display B: as a drive.  though I can navigate to it in the address bar.

What's up with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kinda makes sense now ... It could be a specific design decision to make the windows explorer GUI easier for 'regular' or less experienced users.

Someone reminded me that a non-existent drive B: could be used as a destination to copy from the actual drive A:. It was used by the diskcopy utility that duplicated disk images of floppies, and a prompt would display to swap disks when copying an individual file from floppy to floppy.

So windows explorer could prevent a user from getting the baffling  "insert disk in drive B:" message, when they tried to drag individual files to a drive B: drop target by not displaying that as a target.

Comment: Did you see the [comment](http://superuser.com/questions/612056/windows-7-gui-doesnt-display-a-mapped-drive-b#comment757841_612075) I posted yesterday? Do you face the same issue with local SUBSTed drives as well not showing up as A: and B:?

Comment: Thanks Karan, both Subst and net map work just fine at the command line prompt - but I was wanting to see this in the GUI explorer, where I can't B to appear.

Comment: So even if you SUBST a local dir (*not* a network location) as A: or B: (for example `subst A: C:\Users`), the drives don't show up in Explorer?

Comment: Yes that is correct, In Windows 7 they do not, haven't tried 8 yet but I am assuming it doesn't work there either.

Comment: Weird. As you can see from my screenshot it works fine for me in Win7.

Answer (score 0):

Floppy drives are all but dead, but Windows still reserves those drive letters for them for backwards compatibility.  Yes, you can map drive to A: and B:, however if you have a floppy drive built in, or use a USB drive, then Windows will use A: and B: and It will show up with a floppy icon under My Computer.  Unfortunately, I can only assume its by design (although I dont know why) that Windows wont show you drives mapped to A: or B: under My computer.

Comment: I didn't test with network shares, but it seems to have [no problem at all](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vEDOh.png) with local SUBSTed drives.

Comment: interesting... i tested with network shares.  maybe a bug?

Comment: Perhaps... Can you test with local drives?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 as a OS, Floppy was considered Out-Of-Date as the answer Keltari (user) shows. Although again yes if you use a USB Floppy Drive it will show that as in C:/...shell... for the icons it has a present path for that image and drive letter let alone save one when a CD is used to install that drive.